# Evaluate integral over quadratic form

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

What would be the most kosher way to evaluate an integral like this in Mathematica:
$$\int_\mathbb{R^3} \exp\left((x-b)^tA(x-b)\right)dx \ ?$$
Here $A$ is a real symmetric matrix and $b$ some vector in $\mathbb{R^3}$. Should I write everything out in components and integrate the expression
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp \left( \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (x_i-b_i)^tA_{i,j}(x_j-b_j)) \right) dx_1dx_2dx_3 \ , $$
or is there a more elegant way to do this by staying in the "vector notation" without writing the sums?

Comment: But in other words.

Comment: Most elegant way in this case would be to do this integral analytically. Expand brackets, diagonalize by an orthogonal transformation, complete squares etc.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Yes, I know how to do it by hand. But that is not the topic of this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you give the integral an explicit matrix, then [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) can solve it:

```
A = {{-5,-5,7/2},{0,-10,7/2},{0,0,-3}};

Integrate[Exp[(x-b).A.(x-b)], x ∈ FullRegion[3], Assumptions->b ∈ Vectors[3]]
```

> 2 Sqrt[2/805] π^(3/2)

Comment: The OP mentioned symmetric matrices and in that case there is a symbolic result.  For example:  `n = 3;
A = Table[a[Min[i, j], Max[i, j]], {i, n}, {j, n}];
Integrate[Exp[x.A.x], x \[Element] FullRegion[n]]` as I think `b` can be anything.